# Apache rename httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, apache2.2

It appearsh that the httpd.conf file can be called something else.
For example, my httpd.conf (Apache2.2, Windows 7) is called something like "httpd-LIVE.conf" and another "httpd-TEST.conf".
Could this cause any issues?  Are we free to rename httpd.conf to anything we want as long as extension is .conf?
Thanks

Comment: As this is more of a config question of the server I would suggest asking on Server fault. As it is there is already a similar question there: http://serverfault.com/questions/620125/apache-moving-from-http-conf-to-apache2-conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/configuring.html:

> The main configuration file is usually called `httpd.conf`. The location of this file is set at compile-time, but may be overridden with the `-f` command line flag.

So no, it seems you can not rename it to just anything, at least not without “telling” the httpd executable about it on either compile time or each start.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it